# mostrar perfil de usuario al loguearse php

Tags: php, html, login, modal

Buenas tengo un problema eh intentado durante varios dias poner el nombre del perfil al loguearse  ya que mi proyecto es algo escolar pero lo intento y no me deja eh visto varios videos donde lo intento replicar y salen fallos

nesecito principalmente que se recoga el nombre (cabe destacar que asi lo tengo en la base de datos y la tabla ademas se llama usuarios ) y lo ponga al lado de bienvenidos

siempre me sale algun error con las lineas de codigos cuando lo intento yo soy principiante en php y mysql apenas me estoy metiendo en este lenguaje de programacion. el codigo esta recortado en las partes esenciales.

Por favor alguien que me enseñe como hacerlo o me ponga ejemplos en el caso de que lo hagan me pueden mandar el codigo que a la vez estoy atrasado con esto y que no conozco demasiado de este lenguaje se lo agradeceria demasiado

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['rol'])){
        header('location: login.php');
    }else{
        if($_SESSION['rol'] != 1){
            header('location: login.php');
        }
    }  
?>
```

```
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="item">
    Bienvenido administrador 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut sapiente adipisci nemo atque eligendi reprehenderit minima blanditiis eum quae aspernatur!
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿En la variable $_SESSION que datos guardas aparte del rol ?

Answer (score 0):

Saludos estimado intenta lo siguiente

```
$usuario= $_SESSION['usuario'];

header("Location: login.php?name=$usuario");
```

En login.php

```
<div class="main_container">
<div class="item">
Bienvenido <? echo $_GET["usuario"]; ?>
</div>
<div class="item">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut sapiente adipisci nemo atque eligendi reprehenderit minima blanditiis eum quae aspernatur!
</div>**texto en negrita**
```